# Create a new dataframe based on a list of strings and a interval of dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I need to create a new dataframe that is the result of generating for each of the values ​​of dataframe 2, a time interval per hour. In such a way that dataframe 1 is only a date range and that range has to be repeated for each of the values ​​of the other dataframe.

The value of the hours will always be sorted since it has a start date and end date range.

Input Dataframe 1:

| Date | Hour |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-05-15 | 1 |
| 2021-05-15 | 2 |
| 2021-05-15 | 3 |
| 2021-05-15 | 4 |

Input Dataframe 2:

| Class |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |

Expected Output:

| Date | Hour | Class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-15 | 1 | A |
| 2021-05-15 | 2 | A |
| 2021-05-15 | 3 | A |
| 2021-05-15 | 4 | A |
| 2021-05-15 | 1 | B |
| 2021-05-15 | 2 | B |
| 2021-05-15 | 3 | B |
| 2021-05-15 | 4 | B |
| 2021-05-15 | 1 | C |
| 2021-05-15 | 2 | C |
| 2021-05-15 | 3 | C |
| 2021-05-15 | 4 | C |

Thank!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
new_df = pd.merge(df,df2,how = 'cross')
```

or

```
new_df = pd.concat([df]*df2.shape[0],keys = df2['Class']).reset_index(level=0)
```